# Ideas for using polynomial regression for multivariate time series prediction

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, regression

I would like to predict next 12 months of employee count based on 3 or more years of data that includes salaries, profit and employee count.

I have also interpolated monthly values for these three variables for known years to better suit to the problem and generate more training examples.

Based on analysis I would like to apply polynomial prediction model for predicting employee count at step **t** from **t-1**, then from **t** to **t+1** and up to **t+11** which corresponds to December. I do not have available salaries and profit data at prediction times so I cannot use them as **X** vector to predict employee count **y**.

I tried using **Arima** and it works fine, but it works with univariate series.
I tried also to reframe these three time series in pattern sequences with window or lag 1 and prediction steps 12 which gives (13,39) matrix.

Do you have some ideas how this problem can be approached, how it can be trained and how prediction can be triggered? Also what could be other options for reframing the time series?

Comment: Because the nature of the problem is sequential I recommend LSTMs.

Comment: If you don't have access to a variable in the prediction time, it's not rational to use that variable in training phase. So, it seems you want to predict future employee count just based on the history of the previous employee counts. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I do not know them, but historical data seems to have strong correlation with employee count so I was thinking to somehow use them as supervised learning to predic the employee count.

Comment: Thanks Media, lstm are option definately but I am trying to find some simpler solution.